# In vb.net how to form RegularExpression for text like starts and ends with #

Tags: regex, vb.net

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("#*#")  is this correct..!? 
my text can be like #abc1234+as00# etc. ie, anything between #..#

Comment: Use the LIKE operator, it is easier.

Comment: @user1066231: Can you given an example of how the whole string looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Regex pattern should do:

```
Regex("#(.+?)#")
```

The `.` matches any character, the `+` says to match one or more, and the `?` makes the match non-greedy. The parentheses identify a group.

Comment: The string literal `@` is not needed 1) because this is VB.NET which doesn't have that; 2) Even if it was C#, there are no characters that would require it anyway.

Comment: True, I'm just in the habit of preceding my regex string literals with an asterisk. I've removed it for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

If the entire line consists of `"#..#"`, you could use

```
If s.BeginsWith("#") AndAlso s.EndsWith("#") Then
    s = s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2)
End If
```

Or even simpler

```
s = s.Trim("#"c)
```

Comment: Because the poster says it starts with `#` and ends with `#`, but doesn't say the entire text being processed starts and ends with that pair. IOW, it could be `some bunch of text here #12345-6789# with more text to follow` as the question is written. :) Not downvoting your answer, just pointing out it might not be the solution given the wording of the question.

Comment: Yes, however "my text can be like #abc1234+as00#" suggests its the whole text.

Comment: But it says `my text can be like #abc1234+as00# etc. ie, anything between #..#` - note the `etc.` and `anything between #..#`. It doesn't say nothing can follow. Again, not downvoting, but your answer should probably say "If the entire line consists of #..#, you could use..." to clarify that it works only if the line both starts and ends with `#`.

Comment: Nice, and +1 based on the change. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression:

> ^#.*#$

The `^` anchors the expression to the beginning of the input. The `#` matches another `#`. The `.` matches any character, the `*` repeats that match as many times as possible. The `#` matches another `#`. Finally, the `$` anchors the expression to the end of the input.

--edit--
I misunderstood the request, but I'll leave this answer here as an example of some of what the expression parts mean.

Comment: I tried this "#(.+?)#" and it worked, and looks like yours also works..any loop hole in comparing with your answer..? and am using Vb.net. Ur explanation was really helpful.